# how to translate an array of array elements (different lenghts) into a tree/hash

Tags: perl, metaprogramming

How can I convert programatically a list of arrays like this

```
$dat_a = [qw( a1 b1 c1 d1 e1)]
$dat_b = [qw( a1 b1 c2 d2 e1)]
$dat_c = [qw( a1 b2 c3)]
[...]
```

into a hierarchy (a hash) like

```
# {a1}--{b1}-{c1}-{d1}{e1}=42
#     \     \{c2}-{d2}{e1}=84
#      |{b2}-{c3}=72
```

Populating the hash like this with dinamically generated code:

```
$dat_hierarchy->{a1}{b1}{c1}{d1}{e1} ++
$dat_hierarchy->{a1}{b1}{c2}{d2}{e1} ++
$dat_hierarchy->{a1}{b2}{c3} ++
```

My problem here is that the arrays inside the run have different
length, and that the maximum lenght is also varible between runs.

A similar problem would be to convert file paths to directory trees,
so I asumme that there would be some standard algorithms for solving
this problems.

If I hardcode the depth (or array lenght), a posible solution that I
can think of, is to convert this problem to the more generic one of
converting a matrix to a hierarchy. This imply converting the arrays
to a matrix (adding trailing 0s to have all arrays with the same
length). That way the solution would be trivial (if the script is
hardocoded for the depth/length)

```
#[Perlish pseudocode]
$max_array_idx        = find_maximum_array_index (\@list_of_arrays)
@lst_of_matrix_arrays = fill_to_same_length(\@list_of_arrays, $max_array_idx)
$hierarchy            = create_tree(\@list_of_matrix_arrays, $max_array_idx)

sub create_tree {
    my ($list_of_matrix_arrays, $max_array_idx) = @_;

    # <problem> how to dinamically handle $max_array_idx??

    # if I use fixed depth then is trivial
    # $max_fixed_idx = 2 
    # hardcoded hash construction for depth 3!

    # Trivial solution for fixed hash depth:
    foreach my $array ($list_of_matrix_arrays) {
        $dat_hierarchy->{$array->[0]}{$array->[1]}{$array->[2]} ++      
    }
}
```

So, I would apreciate any suggestions about how to avoid hardcoding
the maximum number of array index used in the hash creation,

A possible solution could be to use some metaprogramming to populate the hash using runtime $max_fixed_idx?.
would it be something like the following a good idea?

```
sub populate_hash {
    my ($array) = @_;
    my $array_max_idx =  @$array - 1;

    # create hash_string " $dat_hierarchy->{$array->[0]}{$array->[1]}{$array->[2]} ++"
    my $str = '$dat_hierarchy->';
    foreach my $idx (0..$array_max_idx) {
        # using the indexes instead the elements to avoid quotation problems
        $str .= '{$array->['.$idx.']}';
        # how to sanitize the array element to avoid code injection in the further eval? what happen if an array element is called "sub {system('rm -rf ~/')}" ;-)
        # http://xkcd.com/327/
    }
    $str .= ' ++';

    # populate hash
    # $str for lengh 3 arrays would be '$dat_hierarchy->{$array->[0]}{$array->[1]}{$array->[2]} ++'
    eval($str) or die 'error creating the hash';
}
```

What about recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, I'd do something akin to below.

The relevant bit in the solution below is  `$sub_hash = ($sub_hash->{$hash_key} ||= {});`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package HashBuilder;

  sub new {
    my $pkg = shift; 
    return bless {}, $pkg;
  }

  sub add {
    my ($pkg,$data) = @_;
    my $sub_hash = $pkg;

    for my $idx (0..$#{$data}) {
      my $hash_key = $data->[$idx];
      $sub_hash = ($sub_hash->{$hash_key} ||= {});
    }
  }

  sub get_hash {
    my $pkg = shift;
    return %$pkg;
  }

package main;

use Data::Dumper;

my $dat_a = [qw( a1 b1 c1 d1 e1)];
my $dat_b = [qw( a1 b1 c2 d2 e1)];
my $dat_c = [qw( a1 b2 c3)];

my $builder = HashBuilder->new();
$builder->add($dat_a);
$builder->add($dat_c);
$builder->add($dat_b);

my %hash = $builder->get_hash();
$hash{a1}{b2}{c3} = 16;

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

This yields the following result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a1' => {
                    'b1' => {
                              'c2' => {
                                        'd2' => {
                                                  'e1' => {}
                                                }
                                      },
                              'c1' => {
                                        'd1' => {
                                                  'e1' => {}
                                                }
                                      }
                            },
                    'b2' => {
                              'c3' => 16
                            }
                  }
        };
```

Comment: Hello Deliria, I was just implementing something similar to yours when I wrote the question but get stuck at `$sub_hash = ($sub_hash->{$hash_key} ||= {});` my mind got blocked trying to find out how to move the hash pointer from one key level to the next. After seen your line it is obvious. Thanks for the instructive answer

Answer (score 5):

I would use something like [Tree::DAG_Node](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree%3a%3aDAG_Node).

```
use Tree::DAG_Node;
my $root = Tree::DAG_Node->new();

my $data = [qw( a1 b1 c1 d1 e1)];

my $node = $root;
for my $item (@$data) {
    my $daughter = Tree::DAG_Node->new();
    $daughter->name($item);
    $node->add_daughter($daughter);
    $node = $daughter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Schwern, I will give a try to this module. Your answer deserve to be picked up as the answer the same that the one of Deliria (each one for different reasons) but as Deliria seems to need more karma than you I will choose his answer and also give +1 to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar problem discussed on [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org) long time ago. I recollect shortest solution was something like this:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @items = (
    [qw( a1 b1 c1 d1 e1)],
    [qw( a1 b1 c2 d2 e1)],
    [qw( a1 b2 c3)],
);

my $dat_hierarchy;
for my $item (@items) {
    eval "\$dat_hierarchy->{'" . join("'}{'", @$item) . "'}++";
}

use Data::Dump;
dd $dat_hierarchy;
```

**Edit:** Caution, the solution has serious security problems with string eval, see Schwern's comment below. I considered deletion, but decided to leave it here as warning to others.

Comment: thanks bvr +1, this was also the simplest approach I was able to think of, but you know, not always is easy to say when metaprogramming is the right tool or a limitation of your language knowledge. So I wanted to see other options. My concern is about the efficiency and I imagine that for large data sets probably the eval() approach would be much faster when you know the arrays in full beforehand (but as always profiling should be done with the specific data.)

Comment: @Pablo Marin-Garcia - I would certainly put it behind some well-named interface, as such constructs might be difficult to read/understand.

Comment: `$item[2][2] = q['.system("rm -rf /").'];` Don't use eval STRING unless there is no other way and never eval data. This sort of thing is even more dangerous behind a well-named interface as YOU might know not to put untrusted data through it, but the person who comes along two years later might not.

Comment: as I put in my question: http://xkcd.com/327/ HAHAHA :-). Not exactly exploiting eval but direct input read to system/programs

Comment: @Schwern - excellent point, I did not realize this problem. Thanks for a lesson. I added a caution message into my answer.